# wdk ddk compiler problems with OutputDebugString

Tags: c++, wdk

I am trying to build the c++ file with WDK build environment and try to see the output in DebugView tool.
So, When I tried the windows method OutputDebugString(L"Inside the method"); in our program and  when I compiled the c++ file, got the following error.

```
error C3861: 'OutputDebugString': identifier not found
```

After that I have include the header file "Windows.h", then I got the following error:

error C2182: 'WakeAllConditionVariable' : illegal  use of type 'void'
 error C2491: 'WakeAllConditionVariable' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from  'int *' to 'int'
 error C2059: syntax error : ')'
 error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'ConditionVariable'
error C2491: 'SleepConditionVariableCS' : definition of dllimport data not allowed

approx 243 error.

Please suggest me the solution.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue using routine DbgPrint instead of method OutputDebugString.
Syntax:

```
DbgPrint("Test");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you include the WDK include file "winbase.h" instead of "windows.h", it should resolve your problem.

Comment: I have tried both winbase.h and windows.h. Both are generating same error.